# One line Scala equivalent of this Python Snippet

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a one line Scala equivalent of this Python snippet

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, raw_input().split(" "))
```

Can some body help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val Array(a, b, c, d) = str.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its not working. Tested on Scala 2.11 REPL